# Node.js blocking the event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an API, and I got stuck at the point where I am mixing asyncronous and syncronous code depending on the incoming request, take a look at the examples below.

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        controller: 'main',
        action: 'main',
        description: 'lists the API functionality',
        access: 'auth'
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/users',
        controller: 'users',
        action: 'create',
        description: 'creates a new user',
        fields: {
            fullName: {
                format: {
                    min: 2,
                    max: 64,
                    minWords: 2,
                    disableDoubleSpaces: true
                },
                description: 'the full name of the new user',
                examples: 'Thomas Richards, Richard Jones, Michael J. Fox, Mike Vercoelen, John Johnson'
            },
            email: {
                format: {
                    min: 2,
                    max: 64,
                    maxWords: 1,
                    match: 'email'
                },
                description: 'the email address of the new user',
                examples: 'mike@grubt.com, lilly@gmail.com, thomas.richards@mail.com, peter@mymail.com'
            },
            password: {
                format: {
                    min: 2,
                    max: 64
                },
                description: 'the password of the new user',
                examples: '123abcdfg, 7373kEjQjd, #8klKDNfk'
            }
        }
    }
];
```

the routes.js file is basically a very essential part of the API, it validates incoming data, routes to the correct controller/action and defines if the method is public, or requires authentication (basic auth).

**api-server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var os = require('os');
var dns = require('dns');

var apiServer = module.exports;
var routes = require('./routes.js'); // Routes file from above.

var req, res, controller, action, serverInfo, httpServer;

apiServer.start = function(){
  prepare(function(){
    httpServer = http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(3000);
  });
};

//
// We need to do this function, we need the local ip address of the 
// server. We use this local ip address in logs (mongoDb) so we can
// refer to the correct server.
//
function prepare(callback){
  var serverName = os.hostname();

  dns.lookup(serverName, function(error, address){
    if(error){
      throw error;
    }

    serverInfo = {
      name: serverName,
      address: address
    };

    callback();
  });
}

function getRoute(){
  // loops through routes array, and picks the correct one...
}

function getAuth(callback){
  // parses headers, async authentication (mongoDB).
}

function getRequestData(callback){
  // req.on('data') and req.on('end'), getting request data.
}

function parseRequestData(callback){
  // parse request data at this point.
}

function validateRequestData(callback){
  // loop through route fields (see routes.js) and validate this data with the ones
  // from the request.
}

function requireControllerAndCallAction(){
  // do actual job.
}

function handleRequest(request, response){
  req = request;
  res = response;

  req.route = getRoute(); // First step for a request, syncronous.

  if(req.route === false){
    // 404...
  }

  // If in the routing schema access was "auth", 
  // this route requires authentication, so do that...
  if(req.route.access === 'auth'){
    getAuth(function(error, user){
      if(error){ // 401 } else {
        req.user = user;
      }
    }
  }

  if(req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT'){

    // Async functions.
    getRequestData(function(){
      parseRequestData(function(){
        validateRequestData(function(){
          requireControllerAndCallAction();
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    requireControllerAndCallAction();
  }
}
```

As you can see, some functions are asyncronous (getAuth, getRequestData) and some are syncronous (parseRequestData, validateRequestData).

Now here is the thing:

Request 1. comes in with method POST, url '/users' and data:

- fullName = 'Rick'
- email: 'rick@'
- password: 'a'

So we loop through the workflow of the API:

1. get the current route (controller: users, action: create) see the second array element in routes.js
2. get the request data and on callback:
   a. parse data
   b. validate data

Now lets IMAGINE, the validation of the data takes 5 seconds (which is retarded, but just for example) and during that validation, a new request comes in, the new request is not handled untill the previous one was finished right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they were synchronous and if they did take 5 seconds then yes, for that instance of the server, requests would be blocked.  That's why it's critical that blocking calls (network, db, file system etc...) calls are async.  The event loop has to keep looping or the whole server blocks.

http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

A key line from that write up is:

> …however, everything runs in parallel except your code

That means expensive I/O should be async but your code can block.  but, it's typically expensive I/O that we're worried about blocking on the server.

'Your code' is typically just handling callbacks from the long running I/O calls, updating your state and then firing off another call.  But that's the beauty of it - when you're updating your state, it's on the main event loop so there's no need for multi-threaded access to 'your' state and code.  No locking, no deadlocks etc... but all the benefits of async and parallel I/O which is the expensive part.

The other key point (which 5 seconds of non-IO work would fall into) is:

> Other than I/O calls, Node.js expects that all requests return
>   quickly; e.g. CPU-intensive work should be split off to another
>   process with which you can interact as with events, or by using an
>   abstraction like WebWorkers.

Also, do expect 'auth' and 'POST' | 'PUT' to ever happen in the same request?  If so, you may have an issue.  getAuth looks to be async but then you immediately go to the req.method check.  At that point, getAuth will still be working.  If you want POST and PUT authenticated then that block of async methods may need to be wrapped with the getAuth async method.

Comment: oke thanks for the answer, is there a way to handle validation on a different thread/core (through clustering/child proccesses), that would be awesome, than validation wouldn't block anything.

Comment: Just make validation and all the calls in the path of a request async.  You also can't make a single request work on multiple cores in node since the event loop is on one thread of one core.  What you can do however is make multiple instances of node to get multi-core parallelism.  There's solutions like: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html

Comment: How could I make validation and all those calls asyncronous then, somehow I got to loop through the data, and validate it, I mean there is no way to make it async right?

Comment: I edited the post.  A key concept is "…however, everything runs in parallel except your code"

Comment: also note the point on non-IO/CPU intensive work which 5 seconds of validation might fall into ...

Comment: Thanks for all the support, your answers where clear. I really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15607/discussion-between-onlineracoon-and-bryanmac)